# Get Twitter's data from URL with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter

I'm trying to get the Twitter data from the Twitter page URL.
I.e. I have this URL http://twitter.com/eBay.

How can I to get followers number, etc... from every URL?

I'd like to use the Twitter API, but I've not an app to register. So it's not possible for me to authenticate, because I'm creating an University Thesis project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using Twitter4J. It's a useful library for Java to parse all of this information. You can find it [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).

As for not having an app to register, Twitter is pretty loose about obtaining credentials, so just create credentials on your personal twitter account and you should be good to go. You don't need a specific app to do it.

It's also important to know Twitter has rate limits on their API calls. You can find that information [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a Twitter account, how can I create credentials with this one?